# What makes these two functions 'public' and 'private' respectively, and what does that mean?

Tags: javascript, oop, private, public

These two functions are from a course I'm taking (https://www.udacity.com/course/front-end-web-developer-nanodegree--nd001). The code and the comments are from the course provider:

```
/* This is the publicly accessible image loading function. It accepts
 * an array of strings pointing to image files or a string for a single
 * image. It will then call our private image loading function accordingly.
 */
function load(urlOrArr) {
    if(urlOrArr instanceof Array) {
        /* If the developer passed in an array of images
         * loop through each value and call our image
         * loader on that image file
         */
        urlOrArr.forEach(function(url) {
            _load(url);
        });
    } else {
        /* The developer did not pass an array to this function,
         * assume the value is a string and call our image loader
         * directly.
         */
        _load(urlOrArr);
    }
}

/* This is our private image loader function, it is
 * called by the public image loader function.
 */
function _load(url) {
    if(resourceCache[url]) {
        /* If this URL has been previously loaded it will exist within
         * our resourceCache array. Just return that image rather
         * re-loading the image.
         */
        return resourceCache[url];
    } else {
        /* This URL has not been previously loaded and is not present
         * within our cache; we'll need to load this image.
         */
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            /* Once our image has properly loaded, add it to our cache
             * so that we can simply return this image if the developer
             * attempts to load this file in the future.
             */
            resourceCache[url] = img;

            /* Once the image is actually loaded and properly cached,
             * call all of the onReady() callbacks we have defined.
             */
            if(isReady()) {
                readyCallbacks.forEach(function(func) { func(); });
            }
        };

        /* Set the initial cache value to false, this will change when
         * the image's onload event handler is called. Finally, point
         * the image's src attribute to the passed in URL.
         */
        resourceCache[url] = false;
        img.src = url;
    }
}
```

Why is `load()` "publicly accessible" while `_load()` is "private"? And what does public/private mean in this context?

The full file if you need it is at https://github.com/YolkFolkDizzy/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game/blob/master/js/resources.js

Comment: "Public" means it can be called from anywhere. "Private" means it is only accessible from within the file that contains this function. Also notice it says that the "Public" function calls the "Private" function, so when you run the "Public" one it still runs the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's private because it can't get called directly... See this line 105:

```
window.Resources = {
    load: load,
    get: get,
    onReady: onReady,
    isReady: isReady
};
```

As the method is declared in the scope, it won't be available anywhere else.

You can see that the code is written inside:

```
(function() {
...
})()
```

It force any function declaration or variable declaration to be appended to the current scope. Without this, variable would be attached to the closest current object usually window. So `_load` is never exported and the only way to call it is by calling one of the method that is exported on `window` in the `Resource` object.

- Public is when something can get called from outside.
- Private is when something can only get called from inside.

In Javascript, usually private attributes are hidden in a scope that is only available to functions created within that scope.

Comment: Moreover, note that many people use the initial underscore ("_") to denote private data.  This is simply a convention, and on its own doesn't actually enforce private access.  But some people use that as their only mechanism of distinguishing public from private.